# how to get dates sorted in ascending order from influx db query, right now its in string format

Tags: python, regex, grafana, influxdb

I have a query

```
SELECT last("date_of_maturity") FROM "maturity_date_data" GROUP BY "maturity";
```

Im getting this values

```
010423
020423
070423
140423
260523
280423
290923
291223
300623
310323
```

The field is string format, but the values are dates.
Need output arranged datewise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to convert your string date to actual date, and order by it:

```sql
SELECT last("date_of_maturity") dom
  FROM "maturity_date_data"
 GROUP BY "maturity";
 ORDER BY to_date(dom, 'ddMMyy') asc
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a python question, it has nothing to do with `influxdb` or `grafana` or `regex` (your tags).  The question becomes:  How do I sort a list of dates in the format DDMMYY in chronological order?   The answer is a python one liner, if you assume the dates are in a list of 6-digit strings in a list called: `results`:

```
results.sort(key=lambda x: x[4:6]+x[2:4]+x[0:2])
```